# How can i populate data from a reference node into another content type?

Tags: rules, nodes, entities

I have two content types. hospitals and referral form. I would like to pull data from the hospital form automatically, example hospital name, address, contact etc when the user fills in the name of the hospital in the referral form.

I have used entity reference but i cant get it to work. It only gets the URL of the node but not the other fields. And also i have used autofill but it only works for a single content type.
If any one has done this before or if anyone has an idea, please do help. looking forward to your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [entityreference_autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill)

> The Entity reference autofill module gives Entity reference fields an option to populate other form fields with data from selected referenced entities.

Comment: Thanks Andre. I have looked at the module but it only works for the content type that is referenced. Or may be i'am missing something. Have you used it before for such a case?

Comment: "If you plan to load the referenced values from another entity type or bundle, you will need to add another instance of the same field to the referenced entity (source).
"

Comment: Thanks. I managed to do it using field collections and Autofill. Thanx again